# Создание скриптов на реагирование изменения в одной из таблиц

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle

Есть 2 базы. Если в одной из них появились новые поля в таблицах то программа сканируя ее это находит и должна создать скрипты на изменения таблицы в Оракле. Ошибка выскакивает при записи скриптов в оракл

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($@"merge into HT_UPGRADE_SCRIPTS using (select :version_number as vn, :scan_date as sd, :table_name as tn, :script as os from dual) src on (version_number = src.vn and scan_date = src.sd and table_name = src.tn)
                                                                    when matched then update set {dest.Type.ToString().ToLower()}_script=src.os when not matched then insert  (version_number, scan_date, table_name, {dest.Type.ToString().ToLower()}_script) values (src.vn, src.sd, src.tn, src.os)", par.ToArray());

Ошибки вылазят такие:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01858: вместо ожидаемой цифры обнаружен нецифровой символ
   в OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   в OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF)
   в Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommandInternal(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass59.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__58()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass59.b__57()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Все решили. Не правильно выставляли порядок записи скрипта